# Is it possible to create a custom dropdown in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm developing react native app and it is base from web app design.
Here's the web design:
[image]

And in mobile:

[image]

Notice on 3 dots  on both web and mobile when click it should show the dropdown selection. This has already implemented in web app but not yet in mobile as I have to search what are available resources to do custom dropdown in mobile. Any reference highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `react-native-material-menu`. It's simple and easy to use.

`npm install --save react-native-material-menu`

```
import React from 'react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Menu, MenuItem, MenuDivider } from 'react-native-material-menu';

export default function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const hideMenu = () => setVisible(false);

  const showMenu = () => setVisible(true);

  return (
    <View style={{ height: '100%', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Menu
        visible={visible}
        anchor={<Text onPress={showMenu}>Show menu</Text>}
        onRequestClose={hideMenu}
      >
        <MenuItem onPress={hideMenu}>Menu item 1</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onPress={hideMenu}>Menu item 2</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem disabled>Disabled item</MenuItem>
        <MenuDivider />
        <MenuItem onPress={hideMenu}>Menu item 4</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try react native option menu
can you refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-option-menu